# React Hooks/Context & Elastictic UI. Problem with fetched data (REST) in function Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks, react-context

I'm quite new to React Hooks/Context so I'd appreciate some help. Please  don' t jump on me with your sharp teeth.  I Checked other solutions and some ways i've done this before but can't seem to get it here with the 'pick from the list' way.

SUMMARY

I need to get the municipios list of names inside of my const 'allMunicipios'(array of objects) inside of my Search.js and then display a card with some data from the chosen municipio.

TASK

Get the data from eltiempo-net REST API. 
Use Combobox async element  from Elastic UI to choose from list of municipios. 
Display Card (from elastic UI too) with some info of chosen municipio.

It has to be done with function components / hooks. No classes.
I'd please appreciate any help.

WHAT I'VE DONE

I've created my reducer, context and  types files in a context folder to fecth all data with those and then access data from the component. 
I've created my Search.js file. Then imported Search.js in App.js.
I've accesed the REST API and now have it in my Search.js

PROBLEM

Somehow I'm not beeing able to iterate through the data i got. 
Basically i need to push the municipios.NOMBRE from api to the array const allMunicipios in my search.js component. But when i console log it it gives me undefined. Can;t figure out why.

I'll share down here the relevant code/components. Thanks a lot for whoever takes the time.

municipiosReducer.js

```
import {
  SEARCH_MUNICIPIOS,
  CLEAR_MUNICIPIOS,
  GET_MUNICIPIO,
  GET_WEATHER,
} from "./types";

export default (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SEARCH_MUNICIPIOS:
      return {
        ...state,
        municipios: action.payload,
      };
    case GET_MUNICIPIO:
      return {
        ...state,
        municipio: action.payload,
      };
    case CLEAR_MUNICIPIOS:
      return {
        ...state,
        municipios: [],
      };
    case GET_WEATHER: {
      return {
        ...state,
        weather: action.payload,
      };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

municipiosContext.js

```
import { createContext } from "react";

const municipiosContext = createContext();

export default municipiosContext;
```

MunicipiosState.js

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer, Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import MunicipiosContext from "./municipiosContext";
import MunicipiosReducer from "./municipiosReducer";
import {
  SEARCH_MUNICIPIOS,
  CLEAR_MUNICIPIOS,
  GET_MUNICIPIO,
  GET_WEATHER,
} from "./types";

const MunicipiosState = (props) => {
  const initialState = {
    municipios: [],
    municipio: {},
  };

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(MunicipiosReducer, initialState);
  //Search municipios
  //In arrow functions 'async' goes before the parameter.
  const searchMunicipios = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(
      `https://www.el-tiempo.net/api/json/v2/provincias/08/municipios`
      // 08 means barcelona province. This should give me the list of all its municipios
    );

    dispatch({
      type: SEARCH_MUNICIPIOS,
      payload: res.data.municipios,
    });
  };

  //Get Municipio
  const getMunicipio = async (municipio) => {
    const res = await axios.get(
      `https://www.el-tiempo.net/api/json/v2/provincias/08/municipios/${municipio.CODIGOINE}`
      //CODIGOINE is in this REST API kind of the ID for each municipio.
      //I intent to use this later to get the weather conditions from each municipio.
    );

    dispatch({ type: GET_MUNICIPIO, payload: res.municipio });
  };

  const dataMunicipiosArray = [searchMunicipios];

  //Clear Municipios
  const clearMunicipios = () => {
    dispatch({ type: CLEAR_MUNICIPIOS });
  };

  return (
    <MunicipiosContext.Provider
      value={{
        municipios: state.municipios,
        municipio: state.municipio,
        searchMunicipios,
        getMunicipio,
        clearMunicipios,
        dataMunicipiosArray,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </MunicipiosContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default MunicipiosState;
```

Search.js

```
import "@elastic/eui/dist/eui_theme_light.css";
import "@babel/polyfill";
import MunicipiosContext from "../contexts/municipiosContext";
import MunicipiosState from "../contexts/MunicipiosState";
import { EuiComboBox, EuiText } from "@elastic/eui";
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback, useContext } from "react";

const Search = () => {
  const municipiosContext = useContext(MunicipiosContext);
  const { searchMunicipios, municipios } = MunicipiosState;

  useEffect(() => {
    return municipiosContext.searchMunicipios();
  }, []);

  const municipiosFromContext = municipiosContext.municipios;
  const bringOneMunicipio = municipiosContext.municipios[0];

  let municipiosNames = municipiosFromContext.map((municipio) => {
    return { label: `${municipio.NOMBRE}` };
  });

  console.log(`municipiosFromContext`, municipiosFromContext);
  console.log(`const bringOneMunicipio:`, bringOneMunicipio);
  console.log(`municipiosNames:`, municipiosNames);

  const allMunicipios = [
    { label: "santcugat" },
    { label: "BARCELONETA" },
    { label: "BARCE" },
  ];

  const [selectedOptions, setSelected] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);
  let searchTimeout;

  const onChange = (selectedOptions) => {
    setSelected(selectedOptions);
  };

  // combo-box
  const onSearchChange = useCallback((searchValue) => {
    setLoading(true);
    setOptions([]);

    clearTimeout(searchTimeout);

    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    searchTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      // Simulate a remotely-executed search.
      setLoading(false);
      setOptions(
        municipiosNames.filter((option) =>
          option.label.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())
        )
      );
    }, 1200);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Simulate initial load.
    onSearchChange("");
  }, [onSearchChange]);

  return (
    <div>
      <EuiComboBox
        placeholder="Search asynchronously"
        async
        options={options}
        selectedOptions={selectedOptions}
        isLoading={isLoading}
        onChange={onChange}
        onSearchChange={onSearchChange}
      />
      <button>Lista de municipios</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Search;
```

also the 
Home.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { EuiComboBox, EuiText } from "@elastic/eui";
// import { DisplayToggles } from "../form_controls/display_toggles";
import "@babel/polyfill";
import "@elastic/eui/dist/eui_theme_light.css";
import Search from "./Search";
import MunicipioCard from "./MunicipioCard";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <EuiText grow={false}>
        <h1>Clima en la provincia de Barcelona</h1>
        <h2>Por favor seleccione un municipio</h2>
      </EuiText>
      <Search />

      <MunicipioCard />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

App.js

```
import "@babel/polyfill";
import "@elastic/eui/dist/eui_theme_light.css";
import { EuiText } from "@elastic/eui";
import React from "react";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import MunicipiosState from "./contexts/MunicipiosState";

import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <MunicipiosState>
      <div className="App">
        <EuiText>
          <h1>App Component h1</h1>
        </EuiText>
        <Home />
      </div>
    </MunicipiosState>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using forEach and assigning the returned value to a variable, however `forEach` doesn't return anything. You should instead use map

```
  let municipiosNames = municipiosFromContext.map((municipio) => {
    return `label: ${municipio.NOMBRE}`;
  });
```

As per your comment:

you data is loaded asynchronously, so it won't be available on first render and since functional components depend on closures, you onSearchChange function takes the value from the closure at the time of creation and even if you have a setTimeout within it the updated value won't reflect

The solution here is to add `municipiosFromContext` as a dependency to useEffect

```
const onSearchChange = useCallback((searchValue) => {
    setLoading(true);
    setOptions([]);

    clearTimeout(searchTimeout);

    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    searchTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      // Simulate a remotely-executed search.
      setLoading(false);
      setOptions(
        municipiosNames.filter((option) =>
          option.label.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())
        )
      );
    }, 1200);
  }, [municipiosFromContext]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Simulate initial load.
    onSearchChange("");
  }, [onSearchChange]);
```

Comment: Hello. Thank your taking the time to answer. My bad i had already changed the foreach to map. the problem i have is on the ```onSearchChange``` method. Wen i try to filter ```municipiosNames.filter``` it doesnt load it ion the search box. but if i try my hard coded array called ```allMunicipios``` it works just fine. So i cant understand why.

Comment: Updated my answer with your additional query

Comment: I've tried adding municipiosFromContext on useEffect but doesnt work. Thanks again for bearing with me  on this one. It's very kind

Comment: Can you check if you receive updat4ed value of `municipiosNames` in onSeachChange function in the second call

Comment: I dont see any updates in my console. neither on the search box that should display info. when i enter some text in the searchbox, it gives me again the whole array in the console. Thanks again

Comment: On search, the change was expected since onSearchChange was only created once. Adding `municipiosFromContext` to useCallback will work there.

Comment: Sorry I didnt understand this last part. Where should i add the municipiosFromContext? I tried it the way you told me before but didnt work. ```  useEffect(() => {
    // Simulate initial load.
    onSearchChange("");
  }, [onSearchChange]);``` this one didnt work

Comment: That did it man!! thanks a lot. Now i got it what you meant. I had to add it to the end of useCallBacK. You've really helped a lot. Thanks again. bro

Comment: Glad to have helped :-)